# Is there a better way to match part of a URL's pathname in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using `window.location.pathname` to get the path of the current page. Pathnames that I'll get will be similar to:

```
H-Foo-Bar-cu-s/9.htm
Some-Thing-sb-s/22297.htm
Foo-Boo-or-Bar-cu-s/553.htm
Random-32-Ness-Can-be-Fun-cu-s/4617.htm
Chicken-Fried-264-Seaturtles-for-Pennies-cu-s/3971.htm
Asymetrical-Banana-Party-p/asy-banana-p.htm
```

Basically, I'm trying to match the page-type suffixes to the page names that come before the last forward slash.

I got it to work but was wondering if there was a better way to do this:
http://regex101.com/r/dX6rZ9

`(-[^-]{2}-[^-]|-[^-])(?=\/.*)`

Comment: Not really. If you know you'll always get the `/` at least the slash the end then you could ditch the lookahead, but that means you'll have to get the first group out of the match rather than just take the match as-is. You can ditch the `.*` as it's really just noise. If you're not guaranteed a `/` at the end then you'd probably have to put `|$` at the end of your lookahead clause though.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
var result = yourPath.replace(/^.+(-[^-].+-[^-])\/.+$/, '$1');
```

Comment: I don't want the words, just the suffixs/page-type identifiers after the words, before the fowardslash. :)

Comment: What you just said makes no sense, to me at least. Please provide an example of a before and after/sample output your are looking for.

Comment: I provided an example in the question. As I stated, I got it to work - therefore, the link is what I want. I'm simply asking if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Your selection seems pretty specific, so the regex might be your best bet. Unless you have a set list of types/possibilities: -cu-s, -sb-s, etc. If that's the case then you can simply iterate through the list and look for the one where `indexOf` doesn't return `-1`.